# how does two phase locking guarantee serializability when you can still have phantoms?

Tags: database-design, transactions, distributed-transactions

The question says it all. In Chris Date's write up on Concurrency he states that transactions that follow two-phase locking are serializable and then says that all transactions that follow repeatable read are serializable. However repeatable reads can still have phantoms. How then can a set of transactions that follow the repeatable read isolation be serializable when phantoms are allowed?